# Why group by does not work in cosmos db emulator?

Tags: azure, group-by, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

When I perform request with such sql query(in cosmos db emulator)

```
SELECT p.p0001_c0001_id as customerId, count(1) as projectCount
FROM p 
WHERE p.p0001_c0001_id in ('c2ff7799-10ed-41bd-9613-5a27485c8573','0160c82e-86b4-4859-9b12-0f998205ddcb')
GROUP BY p.p0001_c0001_id
```

I have this error "Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'GROUP'." If delete group by(and count(1)) request is working.

My code is exactly like first example from MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-group-by

What's wrong with my query?

Comment: can you post a sample collection

Comment: what is the version of the emulator?

Comment: Hi Nikita, may I know if the size of your container is very big ?

Comment: Sory, for late answers - the problem was in old version of azure cosmos db emulator(2.2.2) and group by work after 2.7.0. Sajeetharan wrote correct answer below. The size of my container not very big, it's very small)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked with a sample collection and it works fine on the portal. May be you need to check the CosmosDB emulator version as mentioned in this [**`issue.`**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/42328)

> Azure Cosmos DB Emulator version 2.7.0 or later supports this as well.